# Is there an 'average' algorithm for st_resample()?

Tags: postgis, raster

Currently, the docs for `ST_Resample()` give options for `NearestNeighbor` (English or American spelling), `Bilinear`, `Cubic`, `CubicSpline` or `Lanczos` resampling algorithm.

ref: http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Resample.html

In the same page, they give a link (http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to the GDAL warp resampling methods in which `average` is an option. However, after running it with `average` as a parameter for the `st_resample` function, it spit out the same raster (values are the same) with a different pixel size. The funny thing is, running `st_valuecount` on the two rasters gives the identical number of pixels too which doesn't make sense.

I would like to resample my 10m raster to a 30m raster resolution by calculating the average within each 30m grid. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose that if your function is only changing the pixel size there will not happen real resampling but each source pixel is just projected to one target pixel. Try  to change also the size of the target image to have more or less rows/columns for kicking the resampling to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Probably "average" was added to GDAL some time after ST_Resample() was implemented. Fill a ticket in the PostGIS Trac system and they should add it pretty quickly.

https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/report/17